# Добавление строк в таблицу в SQL-сервере

Tags: sql

Cуществует таблица, состоящая всего из двух столбцов. Нескольким значениям первого столба соответствует одно значение второго. В таблицу необходимо поместить строки. Но одно значение - это параметр @all, который передается в процедуру, а второй выбирается Select'ом - выбирается несколько значений и им должно соответствовать одно - @all.

Всё примеры добавляют строку либо так:

```
INSERT INTO SalesPeople VALUES (1001, ‘Peel’, NULL, .12)
```

либо так:

```
INSERT INTO LondonStuff SELECT * FROM SalesPeople WHERE City=’London’
```

Комбинировать эти два способа не получается, т.е. одно значение передавать как переменную, а другое через *Select*.
Я попробовала сделать так:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CVT
AS

INSERT INTO [SofI].[dbo].[Соотвествие] ([Код срзи]) SELECT [Код срзи] FROM 
[SofI].[dbo].[СрЗИ] WHERE [Категория] = 'СВТ' AND [Код СЗ] <= 5;

UPDATE [SofI].[dbo].[Соотвествие] SET [Код заказа]= @bll;
```

НО проблема в том, что значение второго столбца это ключ одной таблицы и он не может быть равен NULL.
Вроде бы задача простая: необходимо, чтобы нескольким значениям первого столбца соответствовало одно значение второго. Но у меня никак не получается это реализовать! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Комбинировать эти два способа не получается* А почему? `INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3) SELECT @variable1, field2, 'literal3' FROM table2`

Comment: Спасибо, что так быстро  ответили...

Comment: Спасибо, что так быстро  ответили... 
Смотрите:
 CREATE PROCEDURE CVT @ver INT
 AS
 INSERT INTO [SofI].[dbo].[Соотвествие] ([Код срзи]) SELECT [Код срзи] FROM  [SofI].[dbo].[СрЗИ] WHERE [Код СЗ] <= 4;

Это процедура, которая добавляет несколько значений из таблицы "СрЗИ", которые соответствуют отбору, в первый столбец таблицу "Соответствие".

Comment: А зачем тут процедура? для одного-единственного запроса-то?

Comment: Теперь необходимо в эту же строку поместить значение ver
Если сделать так:
 CREATE PROCEDURE CVT ver INT
 AS
 INSERT INTO [SofI].[dbo].[Соответствие] ([Код заказа], [Код срзи]) @ver,  SELECT [Код срзи] FROM [SofI].[dbo].[СрЗИ] WHERE [Код СЗ] <= 4;
Компилятор ругается... Говорит о неправильной конструкции...

Comment: Вообщем скомбинировать не получается, компилятор говорит, что конструкция неверна

Comment: Если сделать так:

        CREATE PROCEDURE CVT @ver INT
 AS
 INSERT INTO [SofI].[dbo].[Соответствие] 
        ([Код заказа], [Код срзи]) VALUES (  ver,  SELECT [Код срзи] 
         FROM [SofI].[dbo].[СрЗИ] WHERE [Код СЗ] <= 4) ;

То же конструкция неправильная

Comment: ГОСПОДИ! AKINA! Спасибо, ВАМ! Я просто тупой жаб! Я ПОНЯЛА!